# How to combine PuTTY automatic logon with width and height settings?

Tags: command-line, putty, auto-login

I saved a session in PuTTY where terminal width and height have been set. Now I want to make automatic logon and found that this could be easily done from command line. It really logs on. But then I searched for an ability to set terminal window width and height from command line and didn't found any suitable options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customise the width and height in one of your putty sessions (remember to save it!), and then load the appropriate session using `-load` on the command line. For example:

```
putty.exe -load "my session" -ssh user@host -pw password
```